# When i am trying to establish the connection to DB from JSP getting the error "TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified"

Tags: oracle, jsp, jdbc

When I am trying to establish the connection to remote DB from JSP, I get the error `TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`

I have configured the ODBC driver and tested the connection and it is working fine. Even the DB is also working fine. The only problem that I am facing is while connecting to remote DB from JSP using JDBC connections.

Also checked `TNSNAMES.ORA` and `SQLnet.ora` files, they are fine.

Please help me in getting this problem resolved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use JDBC OCI driver, verify your ORACLE_HOME variable (and TNS_ADMIN if exists) and be sure you can connect using sqlplus. 
Check your URL http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/urls.htm#BEIDBFDF